# About fork notebook on Kaggle

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kaggle

[Edit / Fork Notebook interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hQWu.png)

As the images above, there are two buttons: the blue one on the right-buttom coner is `Edit Notebook`, And the white one besides is `Fork Notebook`, I just wonder what  `Fork Notebook` means. Can anyone explain it? thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

"Forking" a notebook means making a copy of it as it currently is. When you make edits on a forked copy, they're saved in that copy but don't affect the notebook you forked from. The term comes from [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(software_development)).

As a note, you can edit your own notebooks, but you can *only* fork notebooks you aren't a collaborator on. In those cases, the "Fork Notebook" button is blue.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it. I forgot that there is such a good teacher as wikipedia. :D